# How to refit GridSearchCV on Multiclass problem

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search, gridsearchcv

I'm trying to use GridSearchCV for my Multiclass problem. For starters, wanted to test it on KNeighborsClassifier.

First, here's the code where I define the function which uses GridSearchCV:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

def grid_search(estimator, parameters, X, y):
    scoring = ['accuracy', 'precision', 'recall']
    kf = KFold(5)
    
    clf = GridSearchCV(estimator, parameters, cv=kf, scoring=scoring, refit="accuracy", n_jobs=-1)
    clf.fit(X, y)
    
    i = clf.best_index_
    best_precision = clf.cv_results_['mean_test_precision'][i]
    best_recall = clf.cv_results_['mean_test_recall'][i]
    
    print('Best score (accuracy): {}'.format(clf.best_score_))
    print('Mean precision: {}'.format(best_precision))
    print('Mean recall: {}'.format(best_recall))
    print('Best parametes: {}'.format(clf.best_params_))
    
    return clf.best_estimator_
```

And, here's where I use it, when I try running a K nearest neighbors classifier:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

parameters = {'n_neighbors': [1, 2, 5, 10], 'weights': ['uniform', 'distance'], 'metric': ['manhattan', 'euclidean', 'chebyshev']}

knn = grid_search(KNeighborsClassifier(n_jobs=-1), parameters, X_train, y_train)
```

Under the current state of the above code I'm getting the following **ValueError**

```
ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting, one of [None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted'].
```

As you may have guessed, this might be related to the value of the **refit** parameter for **GridSearchCV** which currently is set to `refit="accuracy"` and this cannot work because the problem is multiclass.
I changed it's value many times, tried **True** or other explicitly stated metrics and nothing fixed the problem. On some of those tries, the error message changed to:

> ValueError: For multi-metric scoring, the parameter refit must be set
> to a scorer key or a callable to refit an estimator with the best
> parameter setting on the whole data and make the best_* attributes
> available for that metric. If this is not needed, refit should be set
> to False explicitly.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I realized my mistake.
**precision** and **recall** don't work with multiclass data. They should be replaced by **precision_macro** and **recall_macro** instead.

Speaking of which, the one place where I tried using them on the code should be also changed into:

```
best_precision = clf.cv_results_['mean_test_precision_macro'][i]
best_recall = clf.cv_results_['mean_test_recall_macro'][i]
```